# Way around to hide parent if :visited link

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension, content-script, visited

I am currently working on a small [**Google Chrome extension** to display the YouTube subscription page like it was before, on a grid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gajjakkaldbncjhbicjhcpbpihpnhblb/).

I had no problem tweaking the CSS to have a look close to the previous one, but I am stuck with something else:
I am trying to find a way to hide videos that have already been seen by the user.

There seem to be no difference at all in the CSS or HTML hierarchy between visited and un-visited videos, so I guess I am stuck trying to find a way using the `:visited` property.

BUT: the browser only allows to change color/border-color/background-color of `:visited` property, and jQuery cannot filter/select the `:visited` property.

Do anyone have any idea of a way around this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

As I read over the first paragraph that the questions is actually about a [Google Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html) and it wasn't tagged for that, I answered it for the request of using using jQuery. Here are some more information on how to access the visited pages in a Google Chrome extension using the `chrome.history` API.

**Google chrome.history API**

In a Google Chrome extension you can access all the visited links if the user grants permission. You have to include this code in your [Extension manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#manifest):

```
"permissions": [
    "history"
],
```

This will result in a [Permission warning](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html) during the installation, informing the user what information your extension might want to access.

Finally you can now use the [`search`-method](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-search) to request visited pages. You can even request all pages if the `text` attribute of the `query` object is empty:

```
chrome.history.search(object query, function callback)
```

This will result in an array of [`historyItems`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#type-HistoryItem), which holds a bunch of 
 information for every page, like the URL, the page title, the last time visited …

**JavaScript**

Unfortunately it is not possible to select the links a user has visited using a combination of CSS and JavaScript. This is due to privacy settings. It's even written in the [CSS2 specification "5.11.2 The link pseudo-classes: :link and :visited"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes)

> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited and unvisited links differently.

You can read more about it here: "[Plugging the CSS History Leak](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/)".

Possible work arounds for your problem could be:

- store the links a user clicks in the [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) or
- redirect each link through a script that stores the link in the user's session or
- subit newly clicked links using AJAX and also store the values in the session

Comment: In [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dWm6x/), you can see, that even if you've visited the first link, the return value of the requested CSS is still the *"normal*" color.

Comment: Actually, you *can* tell if a link has been visited by using the appropriate Chrome-extension API.  **This is an extension question** and extensions can request that privilege.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for pointing to that and for making it clear in the question. I've updated my answer with a short explanation on how the access of visited pages works using the `chrome.history` API.

Answer (score 0):

you may not be able to directly select the :visited pseudo-class, but you should be able to check whether an attribute set by that pseudo-class exists, providing the :visited has at least one difference.

say for example the :visited pseudo-class sets the background to red, you should be able to check for that like so

```
if ($(element).css('background', 'red')){
    // do something
}
```

so i guess that in your case, the css property that is different would perhaps be

```
display:none;
```

so you should be able to check that against

```
display:block;
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. First of all: `$(element).css('background', 'red');` will set the color instead of reading it. And secondly, this will always return the color of the "*unvisited*" style. [Try it yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/dWm6x/).